# Shell Script time control

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am running a shell script which runs for ONCE or twice a week.. 
and this program runs for few hours (depends on how many files) a day..

But problem is, I have to pause this program during the working hours..
for example, if the working hour is 1 am to 3 am, then all the script work should pause and wait till 3:01 am to start again..
i don't have to KILL the current running process if it is running after 1 am..
but whenever it is done with that specific FILE, I have to make it pause for next files..

currently this is what i figure out

```
while true
do
   curr_time= date +"%H%M%S"
   if [ $curr_time -ge 005000 -a $curr_time -le 030000 ]
   then
      echo "Pause for 12000 seconds"
      sleep 12000
   else
      break;
   fi
done
```

So start pausing at 12:50 instead of hoping that everything can phase before 1am 
and sleep for 12000 sec which is about 3 hours and restart..

but the problem is if for some reason, when it wakes up from 12000second sleep and it is not 3 am yet, it will sleep for another 12000 seconds..
how can I go around with this ??

i want it to pause around 1 am (each file process takes about 1 minute but few hundreds and thousands files are there to process) and starts RIGHT BACK AT 3 am..
I don't have to kill it if it passes 1 am.. just pause after that file is done processing.

Comment: Just use a smaller sleep time... each time the script wakes up, it will test to see if it's in the "do not process" window. If it is, it will simply sleep again.

Comment: Why not just send a STOP signal to its pid at 0:59 and a CONT signal at 3:01?

Comment: FYI, I don't think this script can possibly work in its current state.  The `curr_time` string variable cannot possible be `-ge 245000` and `-le 030000`.  Perhaps you meant `-ge 005000`?

Comment: sorry i edited the question.. yes 00500.. Also how can I send a final to pid ? don't i have to know pid in order to do this? what if it changes all the time?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged with bash, you might use arithmetic expansion to just sleep the needed number of seconds.

`sleep $(($(date -d 3:01 +%s) - $(date +%s)))`

`date -d 3:01 +%s` should tell the number of seconds since the epoch until 3:01, `date +%s` the number of seconds since the epoch until now.

The difference should be the number of seconds you have to wait until 3:01.